# Heroku Postgres showing error: syntax error at or near "("

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, heroku-postgres, pg

i'm trying to create a table  using postgres but i get this error 
this the error i am getting my code is fine but i dont know why its saying syntax error

```
2022-08-10T12:42:11.797344+00:00 app[web.1]: Connected To DB
2022-08-10T12:42:11.799670+00:00 app[web.1]: error: syntax error at or near "("
2022-08-10T12:42:11.799670+00:00 app[web.1]: at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:287:98)
2022-08-10T12:42:11.799671+00:00 app[web.1]: at Parser.handlePacket (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
2022-08-10T12:42:11.799672+00:00 app[web.1]: at Parser.parse (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
2022-08-10T12:42:11.799672+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
2022-08-10T12:42:11.799672+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
2022-08-10T12:42:11.799673+00:00 app[web.1]: at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
2022-08-10T12:42:11.799673+00:00 app[web.1]: at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
2022-08-10T12:42:11.799674+00:00 app[web.1]: at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10)
2022-08-10T12:42:11.799674+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) {
2022-08-10T12:42:11.799674+00:00 app[web.1]: length: 90,
2022-08-10T12:42:11.799685+00:00 app[web.1]: severity: 'ERROR',
2022-08-10T12:42:11.799685+00:00 app[web.1]: code: '42601',
2022-08-10T12:42:11.799686+00:00 app[web.1]: detail: undefined,
2022-08-10T12:42:11.799686+00:00 app[web.1]: hint: undefined,
2022-08-10T12:42:11.799686+00:00 app[web.1]: position: '32',
2022-08-10T12:42:11.799686+00:00 app[web.1]: internalPosition: undefined,
2022-08-10T12:42:11.799686+00:00 app[web.1]: internalQuery: undefined,
2022-08-10T12:42:11.799687+00:00 app[web.1]: where: undefined,
2022-08-10T12:42:11.799687+00:00 app[web.1]: schema: undefined,
2022-08-10T12:42:11.799687+00:00 app[web.1]: table: undefined,
2022-08-10T12:42:11.799687+00:00 app[web.1]: column: undefined,
2022-08-10T12:42:11.799688+00:00 app[web.1]: dataType: undefined,
2022-08-10T12:42:11.799688+00:00 app[web.1]: constraint: undefined,
2022-08-10T12:42:11.799688+00:00 app[web.1]: file: 'scan.l',
2022-08-10T12:42:11.799688+00:00 app[web.1]: line: '1176',
2022-08-10T12:42:11.799688+00:00 app[web.1]: routine: 'scanner_yyerror'
2022-08-10T12:42:11.799689+00:00 app[web.1]: }
```

my node version is 18.7.0 and pg version is  8.7.3

```js
const pg = require('pg')
const postgres = new pg.Client({
  connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  ssl: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  }
})
postgres.connect().then(() => console.log('Connected To DB'))
postgres.query(`CREATE TABLE Persons (
  PersonID int,
  LastName varchar(255),
  FirstName varchar(255),
  Address varchar(255),
  City varchar(255)
);`, (_err, res) => {
  if (_err) {
    console.log(_err)
    return
  }
  console.log(res.rows[0])
})
```

Comment: @jabaa ok i have posted code and logs in text

Comment: Are you running the query before you're connected to the DB? What happens when you move the code into `.then`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **integer** instead of **int** 
[postgresql datatype](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html)

so the Correct code is

```js
postgres.query(`CREATE TABLE Persons (
  PersonID integer,
  LastName varchar(255),
  FirstName varchar(255),
  Address varchar(255),
  City varchar(255)
);`, (_err, res) => {
  if (_err) {
    console.log(_err)
    return
  }
  console.log(res.rows[0])
})
```